# HTML table print large column

Tags: html

Windows XP, IE 7

If the data in one of the column in table is more than say 800 bytes, it seems to print partial pages. Previews also appears same (span into multiple partial pages).

What is the best way so that large number of rows with wide columns (fixed width) are printed properly without giving blank or partial page.

Used table with thead and colgroup with width in 14%.

Comment: Can you add some example code?

Answer (score 1):

You can always specify the optional **media** attribute for style/link tag, which indicates the media types you wanna support.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try adding specific css styling for printing:

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml